# MEAN stack CRUD operations update not working

Tags: angular

I am trying to do CRUD operations and everything is working except the update function, I followed https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fhRdqbEXp9Y but changed the names of things to fit the application that I am writing. I do not have any errors, but it will not refresh the form or update a record that already exists within the Mongo DB.

## person.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm } from '@angular/forms';

import { PersonService } from '../shared/person.service';
import { Person } from '../shared/person.model';

declare var  M: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-person',
  templateUrl: './person.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./person.component.css'],
  providers: [PersonService]
})
export class PersonComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(public personService: PersonService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.resetForm();
    this.refreshPersonList();
  }

  resetForm(form?: NgForm) {
    if (form)
      form.reset();
    this.personService.selectedPerson = {
      _id: "",
      address: "",
      city: "",
      state: "",
      zip: "",
      numPersons: null,
      year: null,
      taker: ""
    }
  }

  onSubmit(form: NgForm) {
    if (form.value._id == "") {
      this.personService.postPerson(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.refreshPersonList();
        M.toast({ html: 'Saved successfully', classes: 'rounded' });
      });
    }
    else {
      this.personService.putPerson(form.value).subscribe((res) => {
        this.resetForm(form);
        this.refreshPersonList();
        M.toast({ html: 'Updated successfully', classes: 'rounded' });
      });
    }
  }

  refreshPersonList() {
    this.personService.getPersonList().subscribe((res) => {
      this.personService.persons = res as Person[];
    });
  }

  onEdit(per : Person){
    this.personService.selectedPerson = per;
  }

  onDelete(_id: string, form: NgForm){
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to delet this record?') == true) {
      this.personService.deletePerson(_id).subscribe((res) => {
        this.refreshPersonList();
        this.resetForm();
        M.toast({html:'Deleted successfully', classes: 'rounded'});
      });
    }
  }

}
```

##person.service.ts##

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/toPromise';

import { Person } from './person.model';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PersonService {
  selectedPerson: Person;
  persons: Person[];
  readonly baseURL = 'http://localhost:3000/persons';

  constructor(private http : HttpClient) { }

  postPerson(per : Person){
    return this.http.post(this.baseURL, per);
  }

  getPersonList(){
    return this.http.get(this.baseURL);
  }

  putPerson(per: Person) {
    return this.http.put(this.baseURL + `/${per._id}`, per);
  }

  deletePerson(_id: string) {
    return this.http.delete(this.baseURL + `/${_id}`);
  }
}
```

###person.component.html###

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col s12">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-content white-text">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col s5">
                        <form #personForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(personForm)">
                            <input type="hidden" name="_id" #_id="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="personService.selectedPerson._id">
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input type="text" name="address" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="personService.selectedPerson.address" placeholder="Enter an Address">
                                    <label>Address :</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input type="text" name="city" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="personService.selectedPerson.city" placeholder="Enter your City">
                                    <label>City :</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input type="text" name="state" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="personService.selectedPerson.state" placeholder="Enter your State Code">
                                    <label>State :</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input type="text" name="zip" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="personService.selectedPerson.zip" placeholder="Enter your Zip-Code">
                                    <label>Zip-Code :</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input type="text" name="numPersons" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="personService.selectedPerson.numPersons" placeholder="Enter the number of People living at the address">
                                    <label>Number of People at Address :</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input type="text" name="year" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="personService.selectedPerson.year" placeholder="Year Census was taken">
                                    <label>year :</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="input-field col s12">
                                    <input type="text" name="taker" #name="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="personService.selectedPerson.taker" required placeholder="Who took the Census?">
                                    <label>Census Taker :</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row">
                                <div class="imput-field col s12">
                                    <button class="btn btn-custom right" type="button" (click)="resetForm(personForm)">Reset</button>
                                    <button class="btn bth-custom right" type="submit" [disabled]="!personForm.valid">Submit</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col s7">
                        <table class="responsive-table highlight">
                            <thead>
                                <th>Address</th>
                                <th>City</th>
                                <th>State</th>
                                <th>Zip-Code</th>
                                <th>Number of People at Address</th>
                                <th>Year</th>
                                <th>Census Taker</th>
                                <th></th>
                            </thead>
                            <tr *ngFor="let per of personService.persons">
                                <td>{{per.address}}</td>
                                <td>{{per.city}}</td>
                                <td>{{per.state}}</td>
                                <td>{{per.zip}}</td>
                                <td>{{per.numPersons}}</td>
                                <td>{{per.year}}</td>
                                <td>{{per.taker}}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <a class="action-btn">
                                        <i class="material-icons" (click)="onEdit(per)">edit</i>
                                    </a>
                                    <a class="action-btn">
                                        <i class="material-icons" (click)="onDelete(per._id,personForm)">delete</i>
                                    </a>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The error was in the NodeJS/controllers/personController.js

```
const express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var ObjectId = require('mongoose').Types.ObjectId;

var { Person } = require('../models/person');

// => localhost:3000/persons/
router.get('/', (req, res) => {
    Person.find((err, docs) => {
        if (!err) {res.send(docs); }
        else { console.log('Error in Retriving Persons : ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2)); }
    });
});

router.get('/:id', (req, res) => {
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
        return res.status(400).send(`No record with given id : ${req.params.id}`);

    Person.findById(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) {res.setDefaultEncoding(doc);}
        else {console.log('Error in Retriving Person: ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));}
    });
});

router.post('/', (req, res) => {
    var per = new Person({
        address: req.body.address,
        city: req.body.city,
        state: req.body.state,
        zip: req.body.zip,
        numPersons: req.body.numPersons,
        year: req.body.year,
        taker: req.body.taker,
    });
    per.save((err, doc) => {
        if (!err)  {res.send(doc);}
        else {console.log('Error in Person Save :' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));}
    });
});

router.put('/:id', (req, res) => {
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send(`No record with given id : ${req.params.id}`);

    var per = {
        address: req.body.address,
        city: req.body.city,
        state: req.body.state,
        zip: req.body.zip,
        numPersons: req.body.numPersons,
        year: req.body.year,
        taker: req.body.taker,
    };
    Person.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: per}, {new: true}, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) {res.send(doc);}
        else {console.log('Error in Person Update: ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));}
    });
});

router.delete('/:id', (req, res) => {
    if (!ObjectId.isValid(req.params.id))
    return res.status(400).send(`No record with given id : ${req.params.id}`);

    Person.findByIdAndRemove(req.params.id, (err, doc) => {
        if (!err) {res.send(doc);}
        else {console.log('Error in Person Delete: ' + JSON.stringify(err, undefined, 2));}
    });
});

module.exports = router ;
```

In router.put I had the Person.findByIdAndUpdate with a lowercase p, so person was not defined where Person was.